# Get the active/current clip in Motion Tracking tab

Tags: python

I'm trying to get/set tracking values of the currenct active clip in the motion tracking tab, but I'm having some problems.

Is there a way to get the currently loaded clip without knowing the name? I thought that using `context.active_clip` would work, but that returns None.

Currently I need to loop over all clips with:

```
for clip in bpy.data.movieclips:
    for o in clip.tracking.objects:
        print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `bpy.context.edit_movieclip` is doing that I was looking for.